# Is there anything like Patreon for German authors?

Tags: publishing

I spent quite some time on the website of [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com) and wasn’t able to find but two authors of German language novels (both in the fantasy genre). It seems that Patreon hasn’t got any German speaking followers to speak of. Is there any other platform, where an author writing in German could crowdfund his work?

My impression so far isn’t that Patreon is gaining ground in Germany or Austria.

Comment: Patreon is not a platform for showcasing your work. You showcase your work somewhere else where you reach your target demographic and then ask them to support you by joining your Patreon.

Comment: @Philipp true. What I mean is something like Patreon. I tried to remove the error. Feel free to suggest improvements to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can find German crowdfunding platforms by searching "crowdfunding deutschland" in a search engine, or more specifically "crowdfunding roman" (that is, "crowdfunding novel" in German) or something similar.

There are a few media reports (e.g. [Deutschlandfunk](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/romanfinanzierung-per-crowdfunding-tim-krohn-verkauft.1270.de.html?dram:article_id=384753)) online about Swiss author Tim Krohn, who crowdfunded one of his writing projects on [wemakeit.com](https://wemakeit.com/projects/timkrohn), where he collected 50,000 Swiss Francs. Another of his projects on [startnext.com](https://www.startnext.com/dein-gefuehl-deine-geschichte) did not gain any financing, probably due to regionally limited appeal.

Author Jasmin Jülicher collected 2,000 Euro on [visionbakery.com](http://www.visionbakery.com/stadtdertiefe) for her fantasy novel. There are many more examples, and many more platforms. You'll have to compare your options and find the one that best fits your needs.

In the end, all crowdfunding relies on the marketing that you do, and the platform that collects the money is not the most important aspect of that. What you really need is a *marketing platform*, which could be Twitter (if you have enough followers) or interviews that you do with news media and so on.